# Spring RestTemplate - Need to release connection?

Tags: spring, httpclient, resttemplate

This is my Configuration for Rest Template,

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("myRestService")
    public RestTemplate createRestTemplate(@Value("${connection.timeout}") String maxConn) {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
         connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConn);
         connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPerChannel);

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(100000).build();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestResponseErrorHandler());
         restTemplate.setMessageConverters(createMessageConverters());

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Am using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager for managing the connections.

Its being accessed by the following code,

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restClient.exchange( url, HttpMethod.GET, entity , String.class );
```

Do i need to release the connection after the above call or is it taken care by RestTemplate. If we need to take care of releasing connection.

Please can some one explain/show how to release the connection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should declare the ClientHttpRequestFactory as a bean. By declaring it as a bean, it becomes managed by the Spring bean factory, which will call the factory's destroy method when the application is closed, or the bean goes out of scope. The destroy method of the ClientHttpRequestFactory will close the underlying ClientConnectionManager's connection pool. You can check the Spring API docs for this.

```
@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(@Value("${connection.timeout}") String maxConn) {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
     connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConn);
     connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPerChannel);

    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(100000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
}
```

Then you can use this bean to create your RestTemplate:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("myRestService")
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory factory) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestResponseErrorHandler());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(createMessageConverters());

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain more clearly probably with code samples.

Answer (score 18):

The question which you have asked:
*Do i need to release the connection after the above call or is it taken care by RestTemplate. If we need to take care of releasing connection.*

**No, you do not need to close the connection on the response, if you use resttemplate.**

From the apache httpclient, you need to consume the complete response (EntityUtils.consume(HttpEntity) and close the response.

This can be verified in the [ClientConnectionRelease.java](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConnectionRelease.java)

But RestTemplate does this for you, to verify the same have a look into
[RestTemplate.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java)

Look for method

```
protected <T> T doExecute(URI url,...) {
 try {
        ClientHttpRequest request = this.createRequest(url, method);
        ...
        response = request.execute();
        ...
        if(responseExtractor != null) {
            var7 = responseExtractor.extractData(response);
            return var7;
        }
       ...
       ...
    } finally {
        if(response != null) {
            response.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Where response extractor does the work for you by consuming the response using
**responseExtractor.extractData(response);**

And after extracting the data completely it is closing **response.close()** as well.

Comment: his whole point is to not close connections for each call and use apache PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager to keep socket open?

Comment: Deepak is correct. He needs to close the connection to release it back to the connection pool.

Comment: We were using ClientHttpRequestInterceptor that intercepted the RestTemplate and response was not getting closed in case of some exception.

Comment: Hi, What happens when response is null?

Comment: @AlafAzam Apparently, a problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451808/spring-boot-resttemplate-close-connection-for-null-responses

Comment: when the pool is [total available: 5; route allocated: 50 of 50; total allocated: 18 of 100] starts getting timeout, it has PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with MaxTotal 100, DefaultMaxPerRoute 50 configured, also a ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy with 20 secs, what can be the error ?

Comment: @hipokito is right, there was a confirmed issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29751#issuecomment-1746543057

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is here: `org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor#doExecuteRequest`

```java
    @Override
    protected RemoteInvocationResult doExecuteRequest(
            HttpInvokerClientConfiguration config, ByteArrayOutputStream baos)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        HttpPost postMethod = createHttpPost(config);
        setRequestBody(config, postMethod, baos);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = executeHttpPost(config, getHttpClient(), postMethod);
            validateResponse(config, response);
            InputStream responseBody = getResponseBody(config, response);
            return readRemoteInvocationResult(responseBody, config.getCodebaseUrl());
        }
        finally {
            postMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```